# Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to point users on my wordpress site to a php login file but I am getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function the_instance() on a non-object 
>   in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/quark-child/login-form.php on line 7

On line 7 the code is as follows:

```
<div class="login" id="theme-my-login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
```

Full PHP code from the login-form.php here: http://pastebin.com/M8rGdu7g

The login form is created with the Theme My Login plugin. If I go to `mysite.com/login/` the form works fine, but when I try to point to the full URL path (`mysite.com/login-form.php`) I receive the above error in my log files.

I have other plugins on my site ( A classifieds plugin which requires users to login, also Disqus commenting plugin) which require me to point to the full php URL path in their respective plugin settings.

Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Because `$template` isn't an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin Theme My Login sets $template to an object.

When you go to : mysite.com/login/ you load WordPress which loads the plugin Theme my Login. You are actually going to mysite.com/index.php and then WordPress handles the SEO friendly URL.

The URL mysite.com/login-form.php does not load WordPress and hence it doesn't load the plugin.